# Seperate an array by common value

Tags: php

I have an array which contains orders and items on those orders. Is there a way, within the array, to "group" the order numbers within a tbody or table?

Here is my loop that outputs to a table:

```
foreach ($order as $resultno => $result_array) {

        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Order'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Vendor'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Style'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Description'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['ItemNo'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['UPC'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Size'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Price'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Quantity'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Department'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $result_array['Category'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

}
```

Ideally, I would want a separate tbody per order number. If that order has multiple items, then they would all be on the same tbody. Or at least a blank row between order numbers.

I know how I can do this using a database, but would prefer not to input data just to query it back out if there is another way.

Thanks!

Comment: As long as your query returns the data in order sequence, then you can store the last order number and output something extra when you find the order number has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[here](https://tehplayground.com/cynPviD2jPQAxCl0) is how you can achieve that.

```
$orders = [
    [
        'order_id' => 1,
        'name' => "temp name",
    ],
    [
        'order_id' => 2,
        'name' => "1 temp name",
    ],
    [
        'order_id' => 1,
        'name' => "1 name",
    ],
    [
        'order_id' => 3,
        'name' => "1 name",
    ],
];


$order_ids = array_column($orders, 'order_id');
array_multisort($order_ids, SORT_ASC, $orders);

$count = count($orders);
$i = 0;
foreach($orders as $key=>$order){
    print_r($order);
    $i++;
    if($count != $i && $order['order_id'] != $orders[$i]['order_id']){
        echo "-------------------- \r\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you. I am working on training my brain to think this way so I can figure out the logic part.

Comment: Is there a way to handle this with a multidimensional array, like this: https://pastebin.com/90fJTWhr

Comment: @thomaskessel I'm not able to open your link. can you please share another link ? maybe use this online php http://tehplayground.com/

Comment: No worries. I used your code almost exactly and it worked perfectly for my array. Thank you again!